How to save PCM file and play its audio at the same time?
I made a recorder that has also a playback function (for birding, basically). It captures audio with AudioRecord. While recording, it saves a PCM file (the capture process and save of the PCM are separated new threads). After stopping the recorder, it saves the PCM file as a WAV (this last step PCM => WAV is quite fast).
The problem is that after stopping the recorder, the PCM file takes too long to save (around 15 seconds for each 60 second recording), and I am not able to play the WAV file for playback. In those 15 seconds, the bird just flew away...
So I want to be able to play the song sooner, ASAP. Maybe I can use the PCM file directly before it is completely saved? Or maybe making buffer size smaller/larger?
The audio capture is something like this:
int i, readSize;
recorder = new AudioRecord(...)
short[] sData = new short[BufferSize];
readSize = recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferSize);
for (i = 0; i < readSize; ++i) {...}

The for loop stores the processed data in a LinkedBlockingDeque<Byte> called queue.
Maybe I can play the queue while it is being saved in the PCM file? Can I play this queue? It is PCM after all...

Title is incorrect, you want to reduce the delay between recording and playback. Unless I'm misunderstand and want to deal with echoing/feedback.

Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. This is what I want: First, I start the recording, and the queue is being written. At the same time, the PCM file is being written. I then stop the recording. Then the queue is complete, but the PCM file is still being written (why??), since this takes several seconds. I want to play the queue thing while the PCM file is being written, not while the queue is being recorded (the recording is already stopped). So can I save the PCM faster (e.g., smaller/bigger Buffersize)? Can I play the PCM while it is being written? Can I play the queue directly?

But, of course, if there is a way to substantially reduce the delay in recording the PCM file this would also be a solution.
